# elasticsearch 7.16 use S3-compatible API setting return Failed to connect to service endpoint

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3

## elasticsearch version: 7.16.2

s3 setting:

```
elasticsearch.yml
   s3.client.default.endpoint: ${our own s3}
bin/elasticsearch-keystore list
keystore.seed
s3.client.default.access_key
s3.client.default.secret_key
```

=================
commands:

```
PUT _snapshot/s3-test?error_trace
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": ${our own s3},
    "client": "default",
    "endpoint": ${our own s3 not aws},
    "path_style_access": "false"
  }
}
```

err:

```
       "type" : "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason" : "[s3-test] path  is not accessible on master node",
        "stack_trace" : "RepositoryVerificationException[[s3-test] path  is not accessible on master node]; nested: IOException[Unable to upload object [tests-xE9qIVoPSbKe-wUzA9qGVw/master.dat] using a single upload]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[sdk_client_exception: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]; nested: IOException[Connect timed out];\nCaused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to upload object [tests-xE9qIVoPSbKe-wUzA9qGVw/master.dat] using a single upload\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3BlobContainer.executeSingleUpload(S3BlobContainer.java:492)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3BlobContainer.lambda$writeBlob$1(S3BlobContainer.java:128)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.SocketAccess.doPrivilegedIOException(SocketAccess.java:37)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3BlobContainer.writeBlob(S3BlobContainer.java:126)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.common.blobstore.BlobContainer.writeBlob(BlobContainer.java:118)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3BlobContainer.writeBlobAtomic(S3BlobContainer.java:263)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.startVerification(BlobStoreRepository.java:1677)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService$4.doRun(RepositoriesService.java:392)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:777)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[sdk_client_exception: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]; nested: IOException[Connect timed out];\n\tat com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)\n\tat com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:70)\n\tat com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:75)\n\tat com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66)\n\tat com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.getCredentialsEndpoint(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:58)\n\tat com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.getCredentialsResponse(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:46)\n\tat com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:112)\n\tat com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.getCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:68)\n\tat com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:166)\n\tat com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.getCredentials(EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.java:75)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.SocketAccess.doPrivileged(SocketAccess.java:31)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3Service$PrivilegedInstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(S3Service.java:222)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1251)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:827)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:777)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5054)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5000)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:394)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:5942)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1808)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1768)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3BlobContainer.lambda$executeSingleUpload$19(S3BlobContainer.java:490)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.SocketAccess.lambda$doPrivilegedVoid$0(SocketAccess.java:46)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.SocketAccess.doPrivilegedVoid(SocketAccess.java:45)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3BlobContainer.executeSingleUpload(S3BlobContainer.java:490)\n\t... 13 more\nCaused by: java.io.IOException: Connect timed out\n\tat sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546)\n\tat sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)\n\tat java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)\n\tat sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)\n\tat sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498)\n\tat sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603)\n\tat sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246)\n\tat sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351)\n\tat sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:373)\n\tat sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)\n\tat sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1287)\n\tat sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)\n\tat sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057)\n\tat com.amazonaws.internal.ConnectionUtils.connectToEndpoint(ConnectionUtils.java:52)\n\tat 
com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:80)\n\t... 45 more\n"
```

why? is setting not effect？